# How to get a bitmap to slide down at the top of a view, stay for a bit, then slide back up?

Tags: android, user-interface

I am making a app where the user presses a button and it tells them if they did something right or wrong, so the feedback is going to be an image that appears at the top of the view. The image will either say "Correct!" or "Incorrect". I am imagining this image sliding down at the top of the view when the user submits their answer, stays at the top for a little while, and then slides back up.

I am new to android dev and I am not sure how to do this. Would this count as an animation? How do I get the bitmap to stay for x amount of time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using AnimationSet - first animation to slide down, second to slide back up. The second one should have delayed start time of the amount of time that defines "a bit" to you.

For example:

```
Animation hide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0, Animation.ABSOLUTE, yDelta);
hide.setDuration(animationDuration);
hide.setFillAfter(true);

Animation show = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0, Animation.ABSOLUTE, yDelta, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0);
show.setDuration(animationDuration);
show.setStartOffset(hide.getDuration() + /* delay */);
show.setFillAfter(true);

AnimationSet moveMenu = new AnimationSet(true);
moveMenu.addAnimation(hide);
moveMenu.addAnimation(show);
mMenuView.startAnimation(moveMenu);
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the information. This seems to shift my entire view though, is it possible to have the animation play on top of my view?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly what you need to do is make sure the view you are animating is on top in its container. I am not sure, but bringToFront might help.